# How to fix "KeyError:1" in my python code while splitting the dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to split my time series data into train and test set. But I'm getting `Key Error :1` while running the code:

```
def prepare_data(data, lags=1):
    X, y = [], []
    for row in range(len(data) - lags - 1):
        a = data[row:(row + lags), 0]
        X.append(a)
        y.append(data[row + lags, 0])

    return np.array(X), np.array(y)     

# prepare the data
lags = 1
X_train, y_train = prepare_data(train, lags)
X_test, y_test = prepare_data(test, lags)
y_true = y_test     # due to naming convention
```

> Error msg:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anacondaa3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
>   in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2656             try:
>   -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 # prepare the data
>         2 lags = 1
>   ----> 3 X_train, y_train = prepare_data(train, lags)
>         4 X_test, y_test = prepare_data(test, lags)
>         5 y_true = y_test     # due to naming convention
>
> in prepare_data(data, lags)
>         4         a = data[row:(row + lags)]
>         5         X.append(a)
>   ----> 6         y.append(data[row + lags])
>         7     return np.array(X), np.array(y)
>         8
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anacondaa3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
>   in **getitem**(self, key)    2925             if self.columns.nlevels
>
> > 1:    2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> >     -> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2928             if is_integer(indexer):    2929                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anacondaa3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
>   in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2657
>   return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>   -> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2660
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
>   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess your index error is raised, because you use the index of the dataframe, but it seems what you really intended was to access it position based.

Please try, if the following change of your code fixes the issue:

```
  def prepare_data(data, lags=1):
        X, y = [], []
        index_of_y_column= 0    # change this if necessary
        indexes_of_x_columns= [i for i in range(data.shape[1]) if i != index_of_y_column]
        for row in range(len(data) - lags - 1):
            a = data.iloc[(row + lags): indexes_of_x_columns]
            X.append(a)
            y.append(data.iloc[row + lags, index_of_y_column])
        return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

Btw, if you just want to shift one or more columns, or the whole dataframe (in the last case all data is shifted relative to the index), you can also use the `shift()` method.

E.g. `data.shift(1)` will shift your whole dataframe by one row.

```
data['targetcol_shifted']= data['targetcol'].shift(-1)
```

Will fill a new column `targetcol_shifted` with the value of `targetcol` stored in the next row. If you can use `shift()` I would recommend to prefer it, because it will be much faster, than doing it by hand.